# Compiling .net standard project on Team City

Tags: teamcity, .net-standard

What is needed to compile a .net standard (1.0) project on an Team City agent. Is there an SDK for .net Standard?

I know that there is an SDK for .net core, but I want to build a .net standard project that has nothing to do with .net core.

Please don't answer with: "install Visual Studio" ;-)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use MSBuild for .Net Standard

Answer (score 1):

The same SDK that can build .NET Core Applications can also be used to build .NET Standard libraries.
The ".NET Core SDK" is a distribution of a .NET Core based MSBuild version, the MSBuild assets needed to build .NET "sdk-based" project files, a version of NuGet and the .net CLI which provides commands like `dotnet build`. On windows, it can even build .NET Framework applications (with some limitations).

Alternatively, you can use the version of MSBuild that Visual Studio or Mono 5 include (mono 5 just can't create nupkgs from library projects at the moment).

Answer (score 0):

.NET standard is a subset of .NET Core. To build any .NET core or .NET standard application you need to install the CLI tools on your TeamCity agent. You can get them here: https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#windowscmd

Or you can use Chocolatey to install them:

```
choco install dotnetcore-sdk
```